# How do I generate 2 different documents from the same VisualForce page?

Tags: apex, commandbutton, document

I've figured out how to open a VisualForce page that autogenerates a Word document using a button click:

`<apex:commandButton onClick="window.open('/apex/GrantDoc?id={!Grant__c.Id}');" id="printButton" value="Print Grant"/>`

However, I need to create 2 different documents, using the same data from that one page but in 2 different languages.

This method I've used allows for only one document (I think). Is there some way I can have 2 buttons on my page, to create 2 different word documents, both using the data from that page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with two buttons and the addition of a second parameter to the URL for the `GrantDoc` VF page.

I would suggest using the [ISO 639 language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) to keep the language values standardized.

**Examples**

English:

`<apex:commandButton onClick="window.open('/apex/GrantDoc?id={!Grant__c.Id}&lang=en');" id="printButtonEN" value="Print Grant (English)"/>`

Spanish:

`<apex:commandButton onClick="window.open('/apex/GrantDoc?id={!Grant__c.Id}&lang=es');" id="printButtonES" value="Print Grant (Spanish)"/>`

At that point, your VF page can use the `lang` parameter and determine if it should be displaying text in English or Spanish. You will probably need to modify the `GrantDoc` page to render `<apex:outputPanel />` elements (or similar tags) based on the value of this parameter. (i.e. only show the Spanish elements when `lang='es'`)

Comment: This is an incredibly simple and helpful solution - I knew I'd wind up kicking myself at how obvious it was. Thank you very much for your help, Mark. You should have seen the hideous Rube-Goldberg-style workarounds I was looking at!

Comment: I'd suggest that that URL param is a good place to put the request, but it might make more sense to use Custom Labels and Translations for the values so that when you change the English version, you automatically change the Spanish version.

Comment: Translation Workbench indeed! @Aaron be sure that you are aware of the multi-language features that the platform has which you might be able to leverage here. If you have questions about those things, it would be best to ask another question and post some of the VF that you're using in order for the community to assist with any problems you encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments - it's nice when Salesforce features actually make what I want to do easier! I'll be sure to look into the translation software.